# How to fix "bad receiver type" error

Tags: objective-c

I am making an app that allows you to set the name and number of sides of and then the app will automatically calculate the shapes name. I've been asked to change the number of sides from an `NSNumber` to an `int`. I have done this but now I get a error saying "bad receiver type". What can I do to correct this but keep the number of side property an `int`?

This is my header file for the class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface shape : NSObject

@property int *numberOfSides;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *colour;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *calculatedName;

void waitOnCR (void);
- (NSString *)calculatedName;

@end
```

This is the implementation file for the class

```
- (NSString *)calculatedName {
    if ([self.numberOfSides isEqual: @3]) {
        return self.name = @"Triangle";
    }
    else if([self.numberOfSides isEqual: @4]) {
        return self.name = @"Square";
    }
    else if([self.numberOfSides isEqual: @5]) {
        return self.name = @"Pentagon";
    }
    else if([self.numberOfSides isEqual: @6]) {
        return self.name = @"Hexagon";
    }
    else if([self.numberOfSides isEqual: @7]) {
        return self.name = @"Heptagon";
    }
    else if([self.numberOfSides isEqual: @8]) {
        return self.name = @"Octagon";
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.name ];
}

@end
```

This is the Main file

```
NSLog(@"Enter a number from between 3-8");

int user;

scanf("%d" , &user);

switch (user) {
    case 3:
    {
        shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
        [myShape setNumberOfSides:3];
        [myShape setColour:@"Red"];
        id s2 = [myShape calculatedName];


        NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %i sides and is called a %@", [myShape colour], [myShape numberOfSides], s2);
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setNumberOfSides:@4];
            [myShape setColour:@"Blue"];
            id s2 = [myShape calculatedName];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ sides and is called a %@", [myShape colour], [myShape numberOfSides], s2);
            break;
        }
    case 5:
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setNumberOfSides:@5];
            [myShape setColour:@"Orange"];
            id s2 = [myShape calculatedName];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ sides and is called a %@", [myShape colour], [myShape numberOfSides], s2);
            break;
        }
    case 6:
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setNumberOfSides:@6];
            [myShape setColour:@"Purple"];
            id s2 = [myShape calculatedName];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ sides and is called a %@", [myShape colour], [myShape numberOfSides], s2);
            break;
        }
    case 7:
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setNumberOfSides:@7];
            [myShape setColour:@"Green"];
            id s2 = [myShape calculatedName];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ sides and is called a %@", [myShape colour], [myShape numberOfSides], s2);
            break;
        }
    case 8:
        {
            shape *myShape = [[shape alloc]init];
            [myShape setNumberOfSides:@8];
            [myShape setColour:@"Pink"];
            id s2 = [myShape calculatedName];

            NSLog(@"The %@ shape has %@ sides and is called a %@", [myShape colour], [myShape numberOfSides], s2);
            break;
        }

    }
    default:
        NSLog(@"Shape not found!");
        break;
}
```

Comment: smells like some assignment (Which would be fine in theory but the issue here is SO basic.._ > im voting for closing > FAQs: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."

Answer (score 12):

The `numberOfSides` is not an object, but rather a fundamental data type, `int`, so rather than:

```
int *numberOfSides;
```

You really want:

```
int numberOfSides;
```

And rather than your `if` statements like

```
if ([self.numberOfSides isEqual: @3]) ...
```

You want

```
if (self.numberOfSides == 3) ...
```

And, your calls like:

```
[myShape setNumberOfSides:@4];
```

should be:

```
[myShape setNumberOfSides:4];
```

(You did this for "3", but not the rest.)

Bottom line, replace all the number literals (which are a `NSNumber` object) with integers, and replace any `isEqual` with `==`.